# VueJS v-for access both parameters and event object on event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

Suppose I have nested elements that are repeated with `v-for` like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div v-for="i in 3">
       <div v-for="j in 3" v-on:click="clicked(i,j)">
         {{i+','+j}}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding Javascript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
   methods:{
    clicked:function(i, j){
        //How to access the click event here?
    }
   },
   el:'#container'
})
```

If I use `v-on:click="clicked"` I can access the event (and the corresponding element) in the `clicked` function. But I want to supply the parameters `i` and `j`, how can I both access them and the click event? I want to be able to do this regardless of event (`keyup`, `keydown`, `blur`, `focus` etc).

Comment: supply $event as a param inside clicked($event, i, j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access event object send `$event` as parameter, Vue will assign the event object if `$event` named parameter is found in event handlers.

```
<div v-for="j in 3" v-on:click="clicked(i, j, $event)">
 {{i+','+j}}
</div>
```